# file up and download openapi generation

Tags: spring-boot, file-upload, swagger

I am trying to implement a file upload/download against a springboot server. Implementing manually is already working, but I'd like to generate both server and clients with Openapi.

This does not work and I do not see why. I have uploaded both example to GitHub, so you can see what I have done.

Could you please provide feedback how I generate it the right way or what I do wrong? 
The link: https://github.com/moley/swaggerUpAndDownload

In upload I get:

```
{"timestamp":"2020-04-01T08:53:42.181+0000","status":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"Required request part 'file' is not present","path":"/documentstore/upload"}-400
```

Would be very nice to get a hint to the right direction.

Cheers
Markus